# Add items to toolbar in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm searching for a way to dynamicly add items to a toolbar in Eclipse RCP.

I use the EModelSerivce to lookup the toolbar in the view of my application.

```
List<MToolBar> toolbar = service.findElements(application, "toolbar_top", MToolBar.class , null);
MToolBar toolbar =  toolbar.get(0);
```

Now I need to add some Toolbar items to it. How can I do this?

Comment: You can create something like a `MHandledToolItem` and set all the values it requires but this is complex and I can't find a good example. Normally you add things using a `fragment.e4xmi` or just put them in the `Application.e4xmi` and turn off 'to be rendered' until you need to show them.

Comment: Ok then I will use the e4xmi file to add all the toolitems and use setVisible on the toolitem. But when I set setVisible(true) to the toolItem nothing happens. When I set the visiblity in the e4xmi file to true and use setVisible(false) in my code, the button hides.

Comment: Visible should always be true. It is the 'to be rendered' flag that controls if they are shown or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed all the toolitems in the .e4xmi file. Default the toolitems are hidden by disable the flag on "To be Rendered". When some MPart need to enable a tooltitem it will be enabled by using:

```
toolItem.setToBeRendered(true);
toolItem.setVisible(true);
```

Hiding it when some other part need to be rendered can be done by setting all the flags back to false.